# Insert a user variable to wshshell for a Telnet script

Tags: vbscript, telnet

I am trying to find how to make the Telnet IP address a variable that the user supplies.  The script works fine as it is but there many host addresses that I have to run this script on.  As it is I have to edit the file with the new IP address each time I use it.  The full script has many Sendkeys entries that I have removed.

```
job>
script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim WshShell
set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 160.221.230.127"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "user XXX XXX"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "cci resetapb cancel"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WScript.Quit 
</script>
</job>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt for input using `InputBox`

```
dim res: res = InputBox("enter ip address", "?", "192.168.1.1")
msgbox res
```

Parameters are:

- prompt
- dialog title
- default

Answer (score 0):

Use this example

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

ServerIP = InputBox ("Enter IP")

WshShell.Run ("telnet " & ServerIP)

WScript.Sleep(500)

WshShell.SendKeys("login~")

WScript.Sleep 100

WshShell.SendKeys("password~")

WScript.Sleep 100
```